# Apply theme to view's background color

Tags: java, android, xml

So I have an ImageButton and I could just change its background colour to white, but then it would be also white while using the dark theme. I tried to use the `android:theme` and set it to mine, but it made the button's background colour set back to the default, or changed the whole app's background to that colour.
ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/backbut"
android:layout_width="45dp"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:layout_weight="0"
android:theme="@style/Theme.MusicPlayer"
android:contentDescription="@string/backbut_desc"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:padding="8dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />
```

themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<style name="Theme.MusicPlayer" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue_1</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_1</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Any tips on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I handle such cases:

Create an attribute in attrs.xml (in values folder, if there isn't one, create it yourself) as:

```
<resources>
        <attr name="myBackgroundColor" format="color" />
</resources>
```

There are 2 themes.xml if you are implementing the dark mode with the help of day-night theme. So in the themes.xml file which is located in values folder:

```
<item name="myBackgroundColor">#FFFFFF</item>
```

In the other themes.xml file which is located at values-night folder:

```
<item name="myBackgroundColor">#000000</item>
```

When you want the view to change it's background color accordingly with the phone theme:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?myBackgroundColor"/>
```

That's it, android will handle the rest and pick the corresponding color you provided from  night themes xml if the dark mode is enabled by the user.